# how to expand system path using ruby?

Tags: ruby, path

I'm trying to require modules in my app without using `require ./module` or `require_relative`.

I know that in python you can do:

```py
import sys

sys.path.append("whatever")
```

Then, you can `import` every module in the "whatever" path.

I guess it is possible to do it in ruby as well, but couldn't figure out a better way than:

```rb
ENV["PATH"] += ':whatever'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```rb
$LOAD_PATH.unshift('whatever')
$LOAD_PATH.append('whatever')
```

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/following-the-path

Comment: this works, and I found out that this works as well: `$: << "whatever"`